# "Chevron"-like effect on images and boxes

Tags: css, svg

I tried to create a chevron like mask for images which should look like this, kind of: https://jsfiddle.net/w0rtLz2h/2/

```css
.clip {
  position: relative;
}

.clip img {
  width: 100%;
}

.clip:before,
.clip:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
}

.clip:before {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top right, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, #F3F5F6 50%, #F3F5F6 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top right, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, #F3F5F6 50%, #F3F5F6 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top right, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, #F3F5F6 50%, #F3F5F6 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, #F3F5F6 50%, #F3F5F6 100%);
  left: 0;
}

.clip:after {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, #F3F5F6 50%, #F3F5F6 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, #F3F5F6 50%, #F3F5F6 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top left, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, #F3F5F6 50%, #F3F5F6 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, #F3F5F6 50%, #F3F5F6 100%);
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="clip">
  <img src="http://hotelislandstargroups.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/img4-960x420.jpg" />
</div>
```

I have to make it work for all modern browsers + IE 9, 10, 11 ...

I already tried with CSS triangles (via border instead of gradient) but the problem with that was that you can't apply a width of 50%.

Another attempt was to do it with an SVG `clipPath`: https://jsfiddle.net/ofnrhq2e/

```html
<svg style="display: block;" viewBox="0 0 960 500" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
  <g>
    <clipPath id="svg-mask-header">
      <polygon points="0 380,480 500,960 380,960 0,0 0" />
    </clipPath>
  </g> 
  <image clip-path="url(#svg-mask-header)" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="http://nfornour.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/960x500-beirut-3.jpg" />
</svg>
```

With that one, IE is not fitting the `height` of the image, but the `width`, so it's warped.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with this version that uses SVG data uri background images ... that should gzip pretty well: [Edit 2018-01 small css fixes]

```css
.clip {
  position: relative;
}

.clip img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block; /* fix gap below */n;
}

.clip:before,
.clip:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px; /* hack to prevent rounding error bleed */
  background-size: 100% auto;
}

.clip:before {
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1 1' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='m0 0v2h2z' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.clip:after {
  right: 0;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1 1' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='m1 0v2h-2z' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<div class="clip">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/960x220" />
</div>
```

Comment: Your code looks good with the exception that the graphics don't come together in the middle which will create the "arrow" effect. I tried some other values for the graphic and ended up with this, which looks like what I wanna do. Is that just a soft fix? Is there a better way? Sorry I'm not familiar with svg graphics. `d='m0 0v1h8z` and `d='m1 0v1h-8z`

Comment: It worked for me on all browsers I tested on (windows, chrome, ff, ie) Which browser failed for you? each draws a simple triangle which should be scaled. If you change width of triangle you would need to change the viewBox too `0 0 1 8`. Other things to try: change `background-size: 100% 100%`

Comment: `m0 0v1h1z` means: move pen to 0, 0 then draw a vertical line 1 down then a horizontal line 1 to the right then draw a line back to the start ... making a triangle.

Comment: Yes it scales and its kinda working but in all the browsers I tested it in (windows ff, chrome, etc.) the triangles dont touch in the center of the image at the bottom, do you know what I mean? Thwy should touch so that the images gets kind of a pointing effect towards the bottom.

Comment: Hmm ... is this a retina screen issue? I am not seeing it. Just had a thought: could have a single 100% wide image: viewbox `0 0 2 1` d `M1 1L2 0v1H0V0Z` which should give you a `|\/|` shape ... I've not tried it.